# How to pass variables from variable group between .yaml files with CopyFiles@2?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops

I have one variable group in ADO library which store different paths and some other variables.

In my main "master" pipeline I use it as below:

```
variables:
 - group: myGroupName
 - name: nameOfMyVariable(from variables group) or JustAnyName
 - value: $[variables.nameOfMyVariable] or $[variables.JustAnyName]
```

then in job in the first Stage (for testing, there is only one stage and job for now) I'm trying to using template yaml:

```
jobs:
- template: my-template.yaml
  parameters:
   path: $(nameOfMyVariable) or $(JustAnyName)
```

then in **my-template.yaml** I have this code:

```
parameters:
 - name: path
   type: string
   default: ''

jobs:
- job: BuildSomething
  steps:
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        Contents: |
          ${{ parameters.path }}
        TargetFolder: '$Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      ....
```

Rest is not that important as it just can't find files to copy and when I try to print parameters.path with **echo**  I get error :
*syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator(error token is ".nameOfMyVariable").*

I do not know how to fix it so I can access variables from variable group in some of my templates. Do I need to use ##vso[task.setvariables] or something else?

Comment: hi h00jraq, what is the latest status of your issue, and have the answers helped? You could highlight the answers to benefit more developers with accepting answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want use variable from variable group it is enough to just include this group

```
variables:
- group: myGroupName
```

And then use variable by name $(nameOfMyVariable)

In your example it seems you try unnecessary try to declare this variable again in first yaml example.
This example is additionally incorrect because you are addings dash directly before 'value' keyword and it may cause undefined behaviour.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#specify-variables

Answer (score 0):

Just like Kontekst says, when it comes to variable groups, you don't need to declare the variable names and values in your yaml. Once you declare the variable groups in your yaml, you could use the variables from the groups directly.

And if you are using parameters against templates, for your scenario, I suppose that you could declare the parameters in your main yaml, and input the parameter value into your template. (and you don't have to use the variable groups)

My main yaml as below.

```
trigger:    
- none    
pool:    
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest 
  

parameters:    
- name: pathmain    
  displayName: Source Path    
  type: string    
  default: README.md    
  values:    
  - azure-pipelines.yml    
  - README.md    
jobs:    
  - job:    
    steps:    
    - script: echo ${{ parameters.pathmain }}    
  - template: test-template.yml    
    parameters:    
      path: ${{parameters.pathmain}}
```

My test-template as below.

```
parameters:
- name: path    
  displayName: Source Path    
  type: string          
jobs:    
- job: BuildSomething    
  steps:    
    - task: CopyFiles@2    
      inputs:    
        Contents: |    
          ${{ parameters.path }}    
        TargetFolder: '$Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory'
```

[image]